# Is there a max recommended size on bundling/combining js files due to chunking or packet loss?

Tags: http, resources, chunked-encoding

So we all have heard that its good to bundle your javascript and css into as few files as possible. Of course it is, but it seems to me that the story is too simple.

See if my logic makes sense here.

Obviously fewer HTTP requests is fewer round trips and hence better. However - and I don't know much about bare http - aren't http responses sent in chunks? And if a file is larger than one of those chunks doesn't it have to be downloaded as multiple (possibly synchronous?) round trips? As opposed to this, several requests for files just under the chunking size would arrive much quicker since modern web browsers download resources like javascripts in parallel.

Even if chunking is not an issue, it seems like there would be some max recommended size just due to likelyhood of packet loss alone since a bundled file must wait till it is entirely downloaded to execute, versus the more lenient native rule that scripts must execute in order.

Obviously there's also matters of browser caching and code volatility to consider but can someone confirm this or explain why I'm off base? Does anyone have any numbers to put to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find the reference of the numbers to put to this, but I have read in the past from a reliable source that someone (I think either Google or FB) did a lot of research into efficiency concerns surrounding request concurrency when they were building their CDN, and found that 2-3 concurrent transfers was optimal, when taking packet loss, transport layer overheads and other such factors into account. This applies to a single client communicating with a single server, and a small but noticeable efficiency gain can be found by distributing content from multiple servers - another advantage of using a distributed CDN.

From the bottom upwards - HTTP, being run over TCP inevitably involves many, many round trips at a low level, since each TCP PSH must be ACKed before the next is sent. Given that the Ethernet MTU is 1500 (often 1492 in practice given the abundance of DSL and other ATM-based connectivity) it makes no sense to set the TCP max payload size any larger as this would actually reduce efficiency. Since many (if not all) of the resources used by a web page are larger than ~1.4KB, they will inevitably get "chunked" (fragmented) at the transport layer, and silly TCP payload size settings will result in fragmentation at the network layer as well. Each of these transport fragments, as mentioned, must be ACKed by the recipient before the next is sent, resulting in at least a few round trips.

At the application layer, HTTP itself also supports "chunking", which is a slightly different ball game to the transport layer fragmentation issue. [Chunked Transfer Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) is designed with the concept of persistence in mind, and also offers memory consumption benefits to both the server and the client. While it will make the response *slightly* bigger, it is not likely to result in appreciably more round trips (if correctly implemented) and any additional round trips are simply TCP PSH/ACK pairs, rather than a whole new HTTP request. The idea of chunked transfer encoding is to spilt the body into chunks within the same stream, rather than to split into chunks that will be exchanged over multiple streams. Certainly, the wording of your question suggests that *all* HTTP messages are transfered in chunks, and this is simply not the case. If your server is configured sensibly, only dynamic content and content that is dynamically compressed would be chunked, and even then not everything would be. Most HTTP servers will make their best effort to fit the response into as few TCP packets as possible.

As far as a maximum recommended size goes, I can't given an authoritative answer, but I will give you my views on the matter. Given the already infinite variations that can occur within the bounds of the parameters set out above, the *most efficient* way to do it depends heavily on exactly what you are serving and how you are serving it.

If you are serving a bunch of static content, probably the larger the individual transfer the better overall, with a caveat: say we're serving a web page with a lot of client-side dynamic content (i.e. JS powered stuff) we want the page to load as quickly as possible. But all we need to send at first is the content required to render the initial state of the display - the base HTML is obviously the first thing we need to send, but it's pretty much a given that this will be the case. Next we will need the style sheet that gives the page it's initial layout, and any images that are required - so everything *looks* as if it has loaded. Next we need the Javascript that attaches all the base client side code to the page - chances are this can actually be fairly small. Only when all this has been loaded do we need to get the larger body of the resources, so instead of putting all the references to this in the HTML head, where you have little to no control over the order in which resources are loaded (NB: *loaded* not *executed*), load them dynamically from your basic Javascript file. This allows you to create a page that *looks* as if it has loaded as quickly as possible, but is actually loading the less commonly used resources or resources that are only needed after several user actions later.

If you are serving everything dynamically - passing everything through PHP/Perl/ASP/Insert Server Side Language Here - then you need to take server side execution time into account as well, but the same principal applies. Produce the markup/styles/scripts/images/whatever that are required to make the page *look* as if it has loaded as fast as possible, and anything that takes a long time to produce can be loaded via JS later.

Reading back over this I'm not sure how useful this will be to you or whether it even answers your question, but hopefully it will make for some entertaining (?) reading.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'm not building apps with the sort of volume where every second matters so it's not something that is incredibly pertinent either way but it certainly is interesting. My knowledge of the inner workings of HTTP/TCP is limited to a single college course nearly ten years ago so this is all good info.